# What data structure will find a max object given additional criteria in O(logn) time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm working with an object that has two values: price and rating. Putting these object into the data structure of my choice, I want to find the object that has the highest rating whose price is under a given price, *p*, in worst-case runtime of O(log*n*). For the sake of simplicity, assume all prices and ratings are unique (no two objects will have the same price or rating).

My first instinct is to use a max-heap sorted by rating, but that doesn't guarantee that we'll find an item under the given price in O(log*n*) time. A binary search tree also doesn't seem to help since we can find the max rating in O(log*n*) time, but again not guaranteeing that we'll find anything under price *p*. I feel like a divide and conquer approach would be best here, but have no idea how to store all of the objects. Any ideas?

Comment: Sort by price and take the cumulative maximum by rating. Save the results and binary search by price to answer queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an augmented data structure, a binary heap or a binary tree, sorted by price, with an additional bit of information storing a link to the highest-rated item under that price. You can build this data structure as follows:

- Start by building the sorted structure by price,
- Walk the structure from lowest price to highest, keeping track of the highest-rated item found so far,
- Store a link to the highest-rated item in each node as you walk the structure.

Now you can answer the queries for the highest-rated item at or under the given price by looking up the upper-bound node for the price, and returning its associated item.

Comment: Actually you don't need to store all the objects. You could only store those that have a higher rating than the best so far when walking the sorted structure. Then do binary search on those items.

Comment: @maraca I intentionally didn't say what specific data structure to use, and what to store at its nodes. Heap/tree/array nodes could be just prices, with links to the highest-rated item under the specific price.

Comment: This is not the point I tried to make. If the item with the lowest price has the highest rating you only need to store this one to answer all queries. So unless the items sorted by price is the same as sorted by rating this would be more efficient, less time and less space.

Comment: @maraca That's an interesting observation that deserves its own answer.

Comment: @gmooney8 Building the structure would be O(n log n). This is the only time that you do a traversal of all elements. Once the structure is built, you do look-ups in O(log n) because once you get to the price node, the best-rating-for-the-price is immediately available.

Answer (score 2):

(I think this may be what user2357112 suggested in a comment.) We can use an array. Sort by price. Store index of the element with the highest rating so far, traversing from low price to high. Binary search on price.

```
                  [(p 1, r 4), (p 2, r 10), (p 3, r 11), (p 4, r 9), (p 5, r 1)]
highest rating ->  N/A          0            1            2           2       
under p
```